# Generic Constraints: Guid doesnt implement IConvertable

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic class that I want to make generic. This class accepts objects that have some ID value. That ID could be a string, int, guid, or anything that could be "ToString()"ed. I wanted to impose a generic constraint on my class but the guid class does not implement IConvertable.

Is there a clean solution to impose a constraint that restricts T to IConvertables and Guids?

Thanks

Comment: can't any object be .ToString()'ed?

Comment: A generic, generic, now theres a thought. Perhaps a value type with different FactoryMethod overloads for types might be an alternatibe way to model.  E.g.  var merchantid  = id.CreateFrom(...). Then comparisons can be made easily with appropriate equality implementation.  And you have modelled explicitly too.

Comment: No, no there isn't. The best you can do is have a class constructor which fails if instantiated with invalid parameters. (Taking "`ToString`ed to mean you want it to meaningfully convert both ways.)

Comment: Why do you want the `IConvertable` restraint if all you're doing is calling `ToString()`? Literally everything in C# supports `ToString()`.